# Как осуществить зум к определенному прямоугольнику (SVG rect) внутри локальной HTML страницы в WebView Android

Tags: javascript, html, android, css, android-webview

Дано:
Локальная HTML страница (в assets), которая содержит SVG и в нем Rect определенных размеров.
Страница загружается при старте приложения в WebView.

Как динамически в процессе работы приложения приблизить (зазумить) этот Rect, чтобы он занимал всю видимую площадь экрана, используя WebView.zoomBy или JS?

P.S. Пробовал расчитывать отношение зума к площадям прямоугольников, манипуляции с JS и WebView, но возможно размышлял не так.

Спасибо!

Иллюстрация:

[image: Иллюстрация]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение путем расчета требуемого scale в зависимости от соотношения сторон и размеров дисплея и zoom-factor'а для webView.zoomBy().